# AJAX,PHP call HTTPS SSL CERTIFICATE TO REST SERVER

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have constructed a node.js REST server https://server.mydomain.com. And i am using html/javascript/php for the front end, when i implement SSL certificate on the front-end i run into the following problem:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://front-end.url' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://sistema.url/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I need to make REST requests to the server over https: right now i am using this with http: but i can not find ajax ssl cross domain requests, is this possible? or how can i do this?
this is one example of my requests

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          url: url,
          headers: {
            'token': token
          },
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            name: name,
          }),
        }).done(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          
        }).fail(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
      });
```

Comment: If `http://sistema.url/` is yours, get an SSL certificate for it. If it's not yours, tell whoever controls it to enter the 21st century. No API should be running on plain unsecured HTTP in 2021.

Comment: how can i set ssl certificate in the front end? , i found xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
          }, helps but where can i set it?

Comment: You don't set it in the front end. `sistema.url` needs to be configured on the webserver side with an SSL certificate. Then you make the AJAX calls with `https://` instead of `http://`.

Answer (score 2):

This restriction was purposely implemented to prevent inadvertent use of non-secure content in what is to be a secure conversation.  The resource **must** implement "https" so that it can be retrieved using a secure connection.

Now that we have "LetsEncrypt.com" to hand out secure (albeit short-lived) HTTPS certificates at zero cost, there really is no excuse anymore *not* to use HTTPS in your websites.  (Automated software is readily available to periodically renew your certificates.)